# PharData create tar/tgz - cannot unlink tar?

Tags: unlink, phar, php-5.6

Why can't I unlink the tar file that I created via PharData?

```
try
{
    $a = new PharData('archive.tar');

    // ADD FILES TO archive.tar FILE
    $a->addFile('manifest.json');

}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo "Exception : " . $e;
}

//Now compress to tar.gz
file_put_contents('archive.tgz' , gzencode(file_get_contents('archive.tar')));

chmod('archive.tar', 0777);
unlink('archive.tar');
```

Error,

> Warning: unlink(archive.tar): Permission denied in C:...

I have forced the tar file to 777 but it still does not work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Phar::unlinkArchive();](http://php.net/manual/en/phar.unlinkarchive.php) After removing all references to your archive:

```
unset($a);
Phar::unlinkArchive('archive.tar');
```

**Note:** I think Phar provides a method to compress an archive:

```
$a->compress(Phar::GZ)
```